# C++ code running using WSL Ubuntu, but not able to debug code in VS Code

Tags: gdb, c++17, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to set up my VS code with WSL Ubuntu to run C++ code. I have installed gdb and g++ and able to run code using Ubuntu and VS code terminal. However, when I am trying to debug the code in VS code, I am getting the following error in terminal.

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\\n"
\[1\] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0\<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-pyvj15od.ucf" 1\>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-sl4nyggt.r1b"
```

In debug console, I am getting the following error,

```
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8001189
Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8001191
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

This is the tasks.json file.

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++-11 build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++-11",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
 }
```

The launch.json and settings.json files are not getting generated.